# Como Cargar la variable con un nuevo dato al hacer click angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular5

Estoy intentando hacer que cuando se presione el boton de crear el componente cambie la variable, o que cargue el nuevo titulo que se muestra a traves de la variable "gestion", el cual deseo q se muestre... parece que lo hace pero cuando carga el contenido del componente al cual llama el boton, no permanece el valor cambiado en el ultimo paso... ayuda

Volvi A escribir el codigo, de otra forma y aun asi, parece como si realizara el cambio, tanto de la funcion "estado" como la funcion de "cambio", sin embargo la pag se refresca y vuelve a mostrarle lo que esta por default, no permanecen los cambios...

Aca el .TS

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  
gestion:string="Gestion de Proyecto";
  cambio():void{
    this.gestion = "Gestion de Casos de Prueba";
}
isOn: boolean ;
  estado(): void {
    this.isOn = true;
  }
}
```

Aca el .HTML

```html
 <ul  class="list-unstyled components ">
                    <p><a href="">{{gestion}}</a></p>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Herramientas</a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="crear">Crear</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a (click)="estado()"(click)="cambio()" href="modificar">Modificar</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Eliminar</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </ul>

    <a *ngIf="!isOn"> <app-barrasearch></app-barrasearch></a>
    <a *ngIf="isOn"><app-barraproyecto></app-barraproyecto></a>
```

Comment: en el `html` estas llamando al evento cambio sin pasar ningún parámetro, sin embargo en tu `componente` si específicas un parámetro en la función.. será eso?

Comment: @JesusAlfredo donde usas ([ngModel]) ?

Comment: cambie un poco el codigo, a ver si logran entender mejor que sucede

Comment: YA ENCONTRE LA SOLUCION:
El problema es el href, utilice en lugar de eso routerLink (cap en la L) y funciono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reemplaza el valor `href="modificar"` por `href="#"` del elemento `a` que es lo que esta causando la redireccion ya que el navegador lo interpreta como una url.

Reemplaza:

```
 <a (click)="estado()"(click)="cambio()" href="modificar">Modificar</a>
```

Por:

```
 <a (click)="estado()"(click)="cambio()" href="#">Modificar</a>
```

El simbolo `#` evita que el navegador recargue cuando hagas clic sobre un elemento `a`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora si entendi porque no servia el href... me di cuenta al cambiarlo por routerlink.. no obstante no sabia porq pasaba eso...